# Resolving circular references in probability-graph

Tags: algorithm, circular-reference

*(Apologies, if the title is not accurate/useful, I'm not sure what else to call it... Ideas welcome...)*

Let's say I have a game that consists of several states ***S<sub>1</sub>***, ***S<sub>2</sub>***, ***S<sub>3</sub>***, ... and coin-tosses that transition you from one state to some other state. There also is a state ***W*** where you win and a state ***L*** where you loose. Games always start in state ***S<sub>1</sub>***. What is the probability **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) of winning such a game.

As an example, let's take the following rules to the game:

- ***S<sub>1</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***S<sub>2</sub>***, tails brings you to ***S<sub>3</sub>***
- ***S<sub>2</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***S<sub>3</sub>***, tails brings you to ***L***
- ***S<sub>3</sub>***: Heads brings you to ***L***, tails brings you to ***W***

Now, if I need to figure out what the overall chance of winning the game is (given fair coin-tosses), I can simply start at the bottom:

- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) = 0.5 * 0% + 0.5 * 100% = 50%
- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>2</sub>***) = 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) + 0.5 * 0% = 25%
- **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) = 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>2</sub>***) + 0.5 * **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) = 37.5%

The problem comes in when I, for example, replace the last rule with this:

- ***S<sub>3</sub>***: Heads brings you back to ***S<sub>1</sub>***, tails brings you to ***W***

Notice, how this creates a circular reference where **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>3</sub>***) depends on **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) and vice versa.

I am looking for an algorithm that solves for **P<sub>win</sub>**(***S<sub>1</sub>***) for **any** possible rule-set for an arbitrary number of states and for "coins" that have more than 2 sides (i.e. each state transitions to a random choice among several possible following states including immediate loop-back). I might even be faced with a situation where the "coins" aren't fair, i.e. the probabilities to transition to the next states are not all equal.

I think I remember something that this can be solved with a matrix equation, but I'm not even sure what to call this problem to do a real Google search for an answer... I don't even know what tags to pick. :)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Given all values are probabilities that sum to 1, I *have a feeling* that this problem should always have one unique solution. Is that correct?

Comment: [Cross post.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/951809/17619)

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a Markov chain model. You'll want to set up the state transition matrix P, and then the long-run proportion of time spent in each state, π, obeys the relationship πP=π. If I recall correctly, when you have absorbing states such as "win" or "lose", π should converge to zeros for all other states and the probabilities of win/lose for those two absorbing states.

Comment: So, would one of the eigenvalues of P be "1", and the element in the respective eigenvector that corresponds to my starting point is my solution?

Comment: @MarkusA. That's exactly right. Note that not all initial distributions of your probability need to converge to some stationary distribution, and since you're talking vector spaces (not really, but almost; I think it's actually a simplex, but I'm not sure about that), there may be infinitely many such distributions (i.e. eigenvectors to the eigenvalue 1).